# USA visa cancellation in the past and applying for a new UK visa

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, applications

I applied for the US tourism visa 5 times before and I got it in 2019.  However, I did many mistakes and my visa was cancelled at the border and I didn't enter the US. I admit to my mistakes as I was younger and immature.

Now, I got a job in the UK after passing many exams and I entered the UK 3 times on tourism visas and everything was OK. In the UK skilled worker visa, they are asking about visa refusal in any other countries or refused entry at the border. I don't know what to do? If I answer no, will they discover it? If I told what happened with the US visa, will my UK visa be refused? Is it fair that a single mistake which I did 5 years ago destroys my entire future?
Please help me with this obstacle.
Thanks

Comment: Assuming you got UK visitor visas after your US visa was cancelled, you shouldn’t have any problems provided you did not [breach UK Immigration rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/suitability-previous-breach-of-uk-immigration-laws-immigration-staff-guidance/suitability-previous-breach-of-uk-immigration-laws-accessible) by not *disclosing the US cancellation* when you applied to visit the UK.

Comment: Thank you. I was not asked the above question in my UK tourism visa application, but they ask it in the skilled worker visa.

Comment: The UK visitor visa application definitely asks about *all* past immigration history. I’ve not seen the skilled worker application questions but it’s pretty much 100% guaranteed they are the same as in the visitor visa application.

Answer (score 8):

> I don't know what to do?

Tell the truth.

> If I answer no, will they discover it?

They may, the US and the UK share information.

> If I told what happened with the US visa, will my UK visa be refused?

Not necessarily, but if you lie - very likely.

> Is it fair that a single mistake which I did 5 years ago destroys my entire future?

Fair? Depends who you ask. Is it fair that you've been caught lying before and are asking to trust you again now? The burden of proof is on you, no-one owes you anything. You have to show that you intend to abide by the conditions of the visa, and your track record shows that abiding by the immigration rules is not your strongest attribute.